# testing behaviour of method that scopes outputs into a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a method which creates a key value pair of delivery costs, the key being the type, and the value being the cost.

```
  def calculate_scoped_job_delivery_costs
    delivery_hash = {}
    ['install', 'fuel', 'breakdown'].each do |scope|
      delivery_hash[scope.humanize] = job_delivery_costs.send(scope).inject(0) { |total, item| total + (item.cost_per_unit * item.hour_count) * item.quantity }
    end
    delivery_hash.delete_if {|key, value| value <= 0 }
  end
```

the key is a scope in the job delivery costs model, which retrieves all associated costs with that scope and adds them up. It works, but I want to test its behaviour, albeit retrospectively.

So its core expected behaviour is:

1. it should output a hash
2. it should calculate each scope value
3. it should remove blank values from the hash

So I have written this test (factories posted below)

```
let(:jdc1){FactoryGirl.create :job_delivery_cost, job: job, delivery_cost: delivery_cost}
let(:jdc2){FactoryGirl.create :job_delivery_cost, job: job, delivery_cost: delivery_cost}
let(:jdc3){FactoryGirl.create :job_delivery_cost, job: job, delivery_cost: delivery_cost}

describe "calculate_scoped_job_delivery_costs" do 
    before do
      allow(jdc1).to receive(:timing).and_return('fuel')
      jdc2.update_attributes(quantity: 4)
      jdc2.delivery_cost.update_attributes(timing: 'breakdown')
      allow(job).to receive(:job_delivery_costs).and_return(JobDeliveryCost.where(id: [jdc1,jdc2,jdc3].map{|jdc| jdc.id}))
    end
    it "should retrieve a hash with jdc scopes" do 
      expect(job.calculate_scoped_job_delivery_costs.is_a?(Hash)).to be_truthy
    end
    it "should calculate each hash value" do 
      expect(job.calculate_scoped_job_delivery_costs).to eq "Fuel"=>15.0
    end
    it "should remove blank values from hash" do 
      expect(job.calculate_scoped_job_delivery_costs).to_not include "Breakdown"=>0
    end
  end
```

So in the last test, it passes, why? I have purposefully tried to make it break by updating the attributes in the before block on `jdc2` so that `breakdown` is another scoped value.

Secondly, by changing the state of `jdc2` and its values, this should break test 2 as fuel is no longer calculated against the same values.

```
Here are my factories...

    FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :job_delivery_cost do
        job
        delivery_cost
        cost_per_unit 1.5
        quantity 3
        hour_count 1.0
      end
    end 

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :delivery_cost do
    title 
    timing "Fuel"
    cost_per_unit 1.5
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :job do
    job_type
    initial_contact_id_placeholder {FactoryGirl.create(:contact).id}
    title "random Title"
    start "2013-10-04 11:21:24"
    finish "2013-10-05 11:21:24"
    delivery "2013-10-04 11:21:24"
    collection "2013-10-05 11:21:24"
    delivery_required false
    collection_required false
    client { Client.first || FactoryGirl.create(:client) }
    workflow_state "offer"
    admin
  end
end
```

job has_many :job_delivery_costs. 
job_delivery_cost belongs_to :delivery_cost
has_many :job_delivery_costs
has_many :jobs, through: :job_delivery_costs

I am really struggling with the logic of these tests, I am sure there are more holes than what I have laid out above. I welcome criticism in that regard.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

Remember that `let` is lazy-evaluated; factories within the block are not created until the symbol defined by `let` is encountered in the code. This can have unexpected consequences for things like scopes, where you might think that the database already includes your factory-generated rows. You can get around this by using `let!`, which is evaluated immediately, or by restructuring the spec to ensure things get created in the right order.

I prefer not to do partial stubbing where it can be avoided. For scopes, you are probably better off using factories and just letting the scopes retrieve the rows instead of stubbing the relations. In your case this means getting rid of the code in the `before` block and setting up each example with factories, so that the scopes are retrieving the expected values.